# Save matches (only string) by xPath on a file

Tags: string, dom, xpath, save

is it possible to save all results from a xPath on a file? I am using Chrome to search the class elements in the DOM tree.  E.g. `.//*[contains(@class, 'NAME_')]`.
'NAME_' is always given in the DOM. I don't need the whole Node, just the string 'NAME_somethingElse' on a text file

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this XPath,

```
.//*[contains(@class, 'NAME_')]
```

selects all of the elements you want, then this XPath,

```
.//*[contains(@class, 'NAME_')]/@class
```

will select the associated `class` attributes only, without the elements.